# Regex to get ALL data between > and <

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking making a regex that gets all the data from the following format:

```
">DATA<" returns "DATA"

"> DATA <" returns " DATA "

">.4930894812948cm <" returns ".4930894812948cm "

"> 939j@$%^^ < > << <" returns " 939j@$%^^ < > << "

">DATA< blah blah blah >DATA123< BLah >DATA456<" returns "DATA", "DATA123" and "DATA456"
```

(Quotes in the examples are there to make them easier to read; they should not appear in the real results.)

DATA can be any encoding

`>DATA<` can be located anywhere in the text file so it can be repeated one after another. Also by ALL data I mean all, including `\n`, `\r`, `.`, reserved chars, etc.

I tried `>(.*?)<` but it didn't work.

I'm doing this in Java.

Adding another example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer facilisis neque tellus, eget rhoncus sapien. 
Pellentesque placerat purus non eros auctor ut consectetur magna bibendum. 
Nam sollicitudin cursus >urna< nec varius. 
Pellentesque elit augue, semper non porttitor nec, adipiscing ut ligula. 
Cras accumsan >dolor< augue. 
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. >Sed< >rhoncus< ultrices elementum. 

    >lac
    us<

 Ut elementum condimentum est > pir. < feugiat.
```

Should mark :

```
"urna"
"dolor"
"Sed"
"rhoncus"
"la
    cus"
" pir. "
```

...including the spaces between them and line separators. Hope This helps.

Comment: Tell me you aren't using regex to parse x/html.

Comment: What is the expected result of this: `> sajhgdsjf <  Normal text asdsad a lot dfjkhsdkjf sdfkjdshf > 2348723 < sdfkjsdhfkj`

Comment: assuming I have this code:
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);`
`Matcher m = p.matcher(DOCUMENT);`
`while(m.find()){....return each repeated data....}`
Result should be : " sajhgdsjf " and " 2348723 " without the quotes

Comment: @link_boy, I replaced your block quote with a code block (along with a few other changes) in an attempt to make the question clearer.  Please review my changes to make sure I didn't mess anything up.  In particular, I tried to make it obvious that, in your last two examples, `la cus` includes a linefeed and several spaces, and that `pir.` starts and ends with exactly one space.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the regex you want:

```
>(.*)<
```

You don't want to use the lazy operator (?). The lazy operator makes the wildcard stop as early as possible and still continue the regex (So it stops at the FIRST <), however without the ?, the wildcard is greedy and will match all characters, and then work backwards until it locates the LAST <.

Comment: Doesn't work. in the case I have repeated >DATA< blah blah >DATA< blah blah >DATA< it will return bad results suchs as "DATA >DATA< " etc.

Comment: :( I was so close, it parsed everything except when I had `.` in the data

Comment: Remember to use "matcher.group(1)", since you'll want the first group on this (the one between the first set of parenthesis).

Comment: @nhahtdh , it's not MULTILINE mode he should use, it's DOTALL mode. The inline form of that one is `(?s)`.  In Java as in most other flavors, multiline is the mode that transforms `^` and `$` from *absolute* anchors into *line* anchors. [ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: @AlanMoore: You are right. I didn't use the feature much so I didn't remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Having some difficulty discerning exactly what the OP wants, but...

`>([^<]*)<` will return values between > and <, including any characters (including > and space) that might be in between.

So:

"> ABC <" will return " ABC "

"> AB>C>D<" will return " AB>C>D"

"> ABC" will return nothing

Test case is here: [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/6gqc). (Click the "Java" link.)

Comment: Pattern didn't seem to compile that well.

Comment: @link_boy -- I updated the pattern and added an example on fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If the data that falls between were not random, I would suggest a global + multiline `\>([^\<])*\<`.  However, since the data ***is*** random, I do not think that you could come up with a single regular expression that would reliably capture all possible characters that would fall between `>` and `<`.

Comment: Check the examples again, he wants it to capture < in certain cases

Comment: It won't capture < inside the data though. >DATA<< wont get "DATA<"

Comment: Do we want to capture everything between the first `>` and the last `<`?  I'm not sue how you could distinguish between multiple instances of `> data <` then.

Comment: Yup everything between the first > and the last <

Comment: >(.*?)< seem to be the closests one to achieve what I want but it doesn't cover line breaks or points when I have a multi-paragraphs that matches many times

Comment: Edited my original answer.  Also, I don't know what flags you need for multiline matching for Java, this is just general regex.

Comment: That regex gets only the last one of all the repeated elements :/

Comment: That last one gets anything in between, >DATA< NOTDATA >DATA< NOTDATA >DATA< it marks everything lol

Comment: Ok, my understanding was that you wanted everything between the very first `>` and the very last `<` in the document.  Pulling out the data from multiple `>data<` strings is difficult if they can contain `<` that do not mark the end of the data.  Can you post a larger block of example text in your question?

Comment: For the code block you have posted, a global + multiline `\>([^\<])*\<` search should work, but this won't cover instances such as `>data><<>< text ><data<` where what you want to capture are `data><<>` and `<data`. If there is some logic to `<` and `>` being used in data points, then we might be able to come up with a regex expression. If the data is truly random, then I do not think a simple regex expression will work here.

Comment: The data is truly random between > and <